# UIImage content of file unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to load an image that I have saved inside Document directory. If I print the path I can see that there is the image however, when I trie to assign the path to a `UIImage` the app crashes:

```
static func callSavedProfileImage() -> UIImage{
        //let profilePictureUser = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
        let nsUserDomainMask    = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
        let paths            = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)

        var newImage = UIImage!()
        if paths.count > 0
        {
            let dirPath = paths[0]

            let readPath = (dirPath as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("ProfilePic.png")

            print(readPath) ///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C9F738C1-F747-4C1D-ADBE-251F168444D4/Documents/ProfilePic.png

            let savedProfilePicture = readPath

            if let savedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: savedProfilePicture) {
                newImage = savedImage
            }

        }


        print(newImage)

        return newImage
    }
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newImage = UIImage!()
```

should be

```
var newImage = UIImage()
```

When you declare `UIImage!()` it creates an *implicitly unwrapped Optional* which will crash if unwrapped while nil.

Just remove the `!` to create a normal UIImage, then it won't crash if the image can't be found.

Comment: Thanks .. I have tried without ! and it still crash

Comment: No. Without the `!` it may *fail* but it won't *crash*. If it does crash it's because of something else you're not showing.

Comment: Sorry .. Just checked and without the `!` its not crashing it prints `<UIImage: 0x12f6bb9c0>, {0, 0}` 1 minute to accept the answer

Comment: No problem. :) I'm glad I could help.